# laravel 5.4 error 500

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

few hours ago i put a blog online but but my link doesn't work. I only can see the Main page. If i click on the menu i've got A error 500. Link of the web site 4thquarter.alexandrehamed.com, the db is empty so it's normal if that look like nothing

Thanks for your help ( sry my post look very messy)

here a screen of my htaccess file

[image]

```
exemple of i have route.php:
Route::get('',[
    'uses' =>'BlogController@Index',
    'as' =>'home.content'
]);
Route::get('/blog/{post}',[
    'uses' => 'BlogController@show',
    'as' => 'home.show',
]);

Route::get('/statistiques',[
   'uses' => 'BlogController@stats',
    'as' => 'home.stats'
```

Comment: 500 could mean anything.  You'll need to look at the web server log file.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution with this htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your log file - `storage/logs/laravel.log`. It's likely you haven't set an `APP_KEY` in your environment. If that is the case, generate one with `php artisan key:generate --show` and pop it in your `.env` file.